# Rails 3 to_json include with condition/where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using the following to output a list of JSON records:

```
@team.people.to_json(
      :include => [:user, :statistics => {:include => :attribute}]).html_safe
```

However, I would like to only include statistics that have a certain type_id set on them. Essentially a left outer join with the users and the statistics, where the a `type_id` on the statistic equals some number.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of at least a couple options:

1. In the `Person` model, override `to_json` (or, perhaps better yet, `serializable_hash`) and do your conditional there.
2. Instead of `{:include => :attribute}` do `{:methods => :foo}` and do your conditional in `foo`.

Here's an example of where I overrode `serializable_hash`, if it helps:

```
  def serializable_hash(options={})
    options = { 
      :methods => [
        'client',
        'services',
        'products',
        'has_payments',
      ]}.update(options)
    super(options)
  end
```

I could imagine something above `options =` where you set the methods array to one thing if `type_id` is the number you're looking for, or to something else otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for me, the type_id needs to be dynamic, and this is in the context of a function that returns an active record results set. Essentially I need to be able to add an 'and' condition on the left outer join, of the include. It does not seem possible to do this in Rails, however.

Comment: Could you post your query in your question?

Comment: I have clarified this question and re-asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502184/rails-include-records-with-a-condition-on-the-include Thanks for your help.