# Rails include records with a condition on the include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a function that returns an activerecord result like so:

```
def athlete_statistics(game_id)
  athletes.includes(:statistics).where('statistics.game_id = ?', game_id)
end
```

This returns all of the athletes with their statistics for a particular game. However, it removes the athletes that do not have statistics for that game, and I would like to have them included.

I attempted to remedy the problem like so:

```
def athlete_statistics(game_id)
  athletes.includes(:statistics).where('statistics.game_id = ?', game_id) | athletes
end
```

This adds the missing athletes back in at the end and returns the proper result set, however when I call `to_json` on the result:

```
<%= @games.first.athlete_statistics.to_json(
    :include => [:user, :statistics => {:include => :attribute}]
).html_safe %>
```

It tries to load all the statistics for that athlete, ignoring the where condition (I'm guessing because it tries to lazy load where the association is null)

Is there a better way to go about this?

**UPDATE:**

This approach will **not** work

```
athletes.includes(:statistics).where('statistics.game_id = ? OR statistics.game_id IS NULL', game_id)
```

As it excludes all athletes that have statistics associated with other games. I need the inclusive left outer join provided by the `include`.

Comment: What about trying:
athletes.includes(:statistics).where('statistics.game_id = ?', game_id) + athletes.where('statistics.game_id != ?', game_id)

Comment: @Yarneo, the second part of that is not a valid query as athletes does not have a column called 'statistics,' the where clause works in the first part because of the include.

Comment: thought so... oh well, if there is a way somehow to add statistics=>null to the second part...

Comment: That still wouldn't help as the athletes can still have other statistics just not for that game, see what I wrote under 'UPDATE' in my original post.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but you want to show the atheletes with the statistics for a given game, and show also the other athletes but not show their statistics as they dont have any for that given game. So if you could do for the second part something like atheletes.includes(:statistics).where('statistics.game_id != ?',game_id).update_all("statistics = NULL") , so their statistics field will temporarily for that output show NULL. Not sure of the syntax, but idea-wise

Comment: That's an interesting thought as a short term fix. If I call to_json on the result however, all null statistics will be eagerly loaded, but without the game_id condition.

Comment: It seems like if you get the right results to be returned, the JSON will just naturally be what you want it to be. Have you tried figuring out the native SQL that would get you what you need, and then working backward from there? That's what I might do.

Comment: Also, for what class are you defining `#athlete_statistics`?

Comment: athlete_statistics is defined on game. I took it out of context for the example, in actuality the game_id variable is self.id. The JSON results are not the same unfortunately as they try and lazy load all of the statistics again when I pass to_json the :include for statistics. I know the SQL query, it would be 'left outer join athletes ON statistics.athlete_id = athlete.is AND statistics.game_id = game_id' I don't think you can add additional conditions to an 'on' clause via AR queries though.